# Dynamic background color codes in xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

So, I'm stuck.

I'm trying to read an color code out of an xml file. This xml file will be different everytime my xsl template is about to get generated to an pdf via FOP 0.2.

So my idea was to set an local variable an read an specific part of the xml file, write that into my variable and set this value as my background color. So far I failed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here's what I got so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="color"><xsl:value-of select="HEAD/COLOR"/></xsl:variable>

<fo:block font-weight="bold"  font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="10pt" background-color="#<xsl:value-of select="$color"/>" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center">
    <xsl:call-template name="xxx" />
</fo:block>
```

Of course the parser tells me that theres no way i can use "<" within the background-color element.

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here...

```
<xsl:variable name="color"><xsl:value-of select="HEAD/COLOR"/></xsl:variable>

<fo:block font-weight="bold"  font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="10pt" 
          background-color="#{$color}" background-repeat="no-repeat" background-position="center">
<xsl:call-template name="xxx" />
</fo:block>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated rather than output literally.

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold"  font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="10pt" 
          background-color="#{HEAD/COLOR}" ...
```

Note, that you don't actually need to use a variable here. You could do this too....